# Is there a way to prevent WebView to reload when the device is rotated?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I'm working in a BottomSheetDialogFragment and seems like there is no way to prevent the WebView to be reloaded, even if I'm not calling .loadUrl again.

I understand that Android will recreate the views on rotation. Just would like to know if it would be then impossible to keep the Web state (e.g. some selection) when the device is rotated.

THanks.